# tmux with iterm2 attach a remote session

Tags: ssh, tmux

I'm using the Tmux integrating with ITerm2, which can create a tab in ITerm 2 for each window created by Tmux.

But somehow this doesn't make much sense for the usual SSH scenario, where we first SSH to a remote host and work with multiple windows through Tmux.

I want to have multiple tabs in ITerm 2, sharing one SSH connection, and in one Tmux sesson. Is it possible?

Comment: See [a question on how to attach to different windows of the same session](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24274/attach-to-different-windows-in-session).

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/questions/741769/remote-server-iterm2-and-tmux-integration

Answer (score 4):

You have to install tmux 1.8 or newer on remote host. Then run `tmux -CC` in SSH session of this host and iTerm2 will attach to tmux running in this session.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. `tmux` communicates through a socket file that the remote end of the ssh session wouldn't be able to see. While other types of data can be tunneled through ssh, I'm not sure you can do this. I work in the same way you do, but I just use the tmux native windows in one tab.